# Converting user input to a number

Tags: r, if-statement

It might be a silly mistake but I'm not able to figure it out.
Here's the sample:

```
 if(K<=50 & k<=K) {
  cat("Message A", "\n")
 } else {
    if(K>50) {
     cat("Error A","\n")
     return(0)
    } else {
       cat("Error B","\n")
       return(0)
      }
   }
```

If I enter K = 9 and k = 2, I still get Error A and the program stops.
Why?

EDIT:
If I take user input for K and k, it gives the "Error A" message. "Error B" works fine. I never get "Message A"

```
K<-readline("Enter K: ")
k<-readline("Enter k: ")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  I get `Message A` when `K <- 9; k <- 2`

Comment: if i use K<-9 and k<-2, it works, but if I use readline() to take user values for K and k, it gives the error I mentioned.

Comment: @PrafullaShahi you should convert the (text) input from `readline` with `as.numeric`.

Comment: @josilber Post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @PrafullaShahi you should look into learning some better debugging approaches. The first thing you should do in this case is check `k > 50` directly, and `class(k)` - that would've led you to the answer and not this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this error is that the `readline` function returns a string instead of a number. When R compares between a string and a number, it will convert both to a string and compare them alphabetically:

```
"9" <= 50
# [1] FALSE
"1" <= 50
# [1] TRUE
```

The solution is to convert the inputted values to the numeric type:

```
K <- as.numeric(readline("Enter K: "))
k <- as.numeric(readline("Enter k: "))
```

Note that if you enter something that's not a number then R will store that value as `NA`; you can check for this with the `is.na` function.